# Div with mouseEvent, with child div with mouse event - click outer div, get both events to fire

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have **Div A**, with a child **Div B**.  Both have a mouse click assigned to them.  How might I be able to click **Div A**, and have both **Div A**'s and **Div B**'s events triggered?  I've looked into event bubbling but all my attempts to make this happen have failed so far.

I am assigning mouse events as such:

```
elem.addEventListener( 'click', myResponseFunction, true );
```

I tried setting the bubbling to true and false on both or one or the other and have had no success.  Is this possible?  No jQuery solutions please.

Further clarification:

Consider an expandable ad with tiles in the collapsed portion that can either be video or synopsis, determined at runtime from a data provider. I want the ad to expand when clicked anywhere in the collapsed portion, but if a "view video" button or "view synopsis" button is below the click-to-expand button, I'd like the ad to advance to the appropriate view after expanding. I desired a cleaner approach, if possible, than putting the expand action on each tile's call-to-action button.  Each tile is a div with a background image and call-to-action button, all covered by and click-to-expand button.

Comment: Um, if you click on A, there is no bubbling to its children since bubbling goes up through parents, not down to children...

Comment: I once heard a wise comment.  The moment you start a sentence with "um" you infer a level of superiority.  Now clearly I'm asking because I am not familiar enough with this topic to solve my problem, so your snark is rather obnoxious.  I guess someone with your superhuman SO score must have never had to ask questions before.

Comment: Wowzers, calm down. To me what you are trying to do sounds like you are trying to get around a bug. Why would you need to click the child element? It is rather complicated since in the parent's onclick function, it would need to check to see if the click was initiated in the child so it does not cause an infinite loop. You need to learn how to trigger the events so find a better way to code it so you do not have to click the children.

Comment: Sorry, its been a 70+ hour week and I'm still at my desk, my patience is a bit challenged right now.  Consider an expandable ad with tiles in the collapsed portion that can either be video or synopsis, determined at runtime from a data provider.  I want the ad to expand when clicked anywhere in the collapsed portion, but if a "view video" button or "view synopsis" button is below the click to expand button, I'd like the ad to advance to the appropriate view after expanding.  I desired a cleaner approach, if possible, than putting the expand action on each tile's call to action button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click events are only triggered on those elements that are under mouse/touch pointer.

Bubbling (up) means that once a child element has processed a click event it then triggers another event of the same type on it's parent element. This process repeats all the way up to the `document` element. What you want is bubbling down. Unfortunately that concept doesn't exist in JavaScript.

A pragmatic solution is to iterate over all child nodes and trigger click events manually when a parent node is clicked. There will be one side effect: mouse events bubble up by default and so when a child node is clicked, it's parent will also receive a click event. This can be easily solved by stopping event propagation further up inside of a child click event handler.

Here is a complete sample:

```js
document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('hello from parent');

    var children = this.children;
    [].forEach.call(children, function(elem) {
        elem.click();
    });
});

document.querySelector('.child').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('hello from child');
});
```

```css
.parent {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.child {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Given my updated question, would you feel this approach would work for me?  I'm still trying to wrap my head around how to work this into my existing code.

Comment: Yes, this approach will still work. You will need to add a few more things to the click events to make it work. If you add a sample HTML layout I might help you further with JS code

Comment: If anybody's wondering, if the parent happens to be an `a` element, then also do `event.preventDefault()` to stop the link from being followed (just don't do that if the child is an `a` 'cause it will stop the child link too).